# How to select a subset from a Multi-Index Dataframe based on conditions from another DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a dataframe like below:

```
                     dates         0
numbers letters               
0       a       2013-01-01  0.261092
                2013-01-02 -1.267770
                2013-01-03  0.008230
        b       2013-01-01 -1.515866
                2013-01-02  0.351942
                2013-01-03 -0.245463
        c       2013-01-01 -0.253103
                2013-01-02 -0.385411
                2013-01-03 -1.740821
1       a       2013-01-01 -0.108325
                2013-01-02 -0.212350
                2013-01-03  0.021097
        b       2013-01-01 -1.922214
                2013-01-02 -1.769003
                2013-01-03 -0.594216
        c       2013-01-01 -0.419775
                2013-01-02  1.511700
                2013-01-03  0.994332
2       a       2013-01-01 -0.020299
                2013-01-02 -0.749474
                2013-01-03 -1.478558
        b       2013-01-01 -1.357671
                2013-01-02  0.161185
                2013-01-03 -0.658246
        c       2013-01-01 -0.564796
                2013-01-02 -0.333106
                2013-01-03 -2.814611
```

Now I was given a list like:

```
   numbers letters
0        0       b
1        1       c
```

I need to select data whose indexs satisfy the list. The answer is like:

```
                     dates         0
numbers letters               
0       b       2013-01-01 -1.515866
                2013-01-02  0.351942
                2013-01-03 -0.245463
1       c       2013-01-01 -0.419775
                2013-01-02  1.511700
                2013-01-03  0.994332
```

How can I select the specific data from the Dataframe of MultiIndex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use index intersection:

```
In [39]: l
Out[39]:
   numbers letters
0        0       b
1        1       c


In [40]: df.loc[df.index.intersection(l.set_index(['numbers','letters']).index)]
Out[40]:
                      dates         0
numbers letters
0       b        2013-01-01 -1.515866
        b        2013-01-02  0.351942
        b        2013-01-03 -0.245463
1       c        2013-01-01 -0.108325
        c        2013-01-02 -0.212350
        c        2013-01-03  0.021097
        c        2013-01-01 -0.419775
        c        2013-01-02  1.511700
        c        2013-01-03  0.994332
```

Or [more straightforward and faster solution from @Javier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42733118/how-to-select-a-subset-from-a-multi-index-dataframe-based-on-conditions-from-ano/42733517?noredirect=1#comment72586876_42733517):

```
In [155]: df.loc[l.set_index(['numbers','letters']).index]
Out[155]:
                      dates         0
numbers letters
0       b        2013-01-01 -1.515866
        b        2013-01-02  0.351942
        b        2013-01-03 -0.245463
1       c        2013-01-01 -0.108325
        c        2013-01-02 -0.212350
        c        2013-01-03  0.021097
        c        2013-01-01 -0.419775
        c        2013-01-02  1.511700
        c        2013-01-03  0.994332
```

**Timing:**

for 27.000 rows Multi-Index DF

```
In [156]: df = pd.concat([df.reset_index()] * 10**3, ignore_index=True).set_index(['numbers','letters'])

In [157]: df.shape
Out[157]: (27000, 2)

In [158]: %%timeit
     ...: q = l.apply(lambda r: "(numbers == {} and letters == '{}')".format(r.numbers, r.letters),
     ...:             axis=1) \
     ...:      .str.cat(sep=' or ')
     ...: df.query(q)
     ...:
10 loops, best of 3: 21.3 ms per loop

In [159]: %%timeit
     ...: df.loc[l.set_index(['numbers','letters']).index]
     ...:
10 loops, best of 3: 20.2 ms per loop

In [160]: %%timeit
     ...: df.loc[df.index.intersection(l.set_index(['numbers','letters']).index)]
     ...:
10 loops, best of 3: 27.2 ms per loop
```

for 270.000 rows Multi-Index DF

```
In [163]: %%timeit
     ...: q = l.apply(lambda r: "(numbers == {} and letters == '{}')".format(r.numbers, r.letters),
     ...:             axis=1) \
     ...:      .str.cat(sep=' or ')
     ...: df.query(q)
     ...:
10 loops, best of 3: 117 ms per loop

In [164]: %%timeit
     ...: df.loc[l.set_index(['numbers','letters']).index]
     ...:
1 loop, best of 3: 142 ms per loop

In [165]: %%timeit
     ...: df.loc[df.index.intersection(l.set_index(['numbers','letters']).index)]
     ...:
10 loops, best of 3: 185 ms per loop
```

**Conclusion:** `df.query()` method which uses `numexpr` module internaly seems to be faster for bigger DFs

Comment: Access by index is generally the best idea when dataframes get large

Comment: @Javier, i thinks you are right. Thank you for your comment!

Comment: @Javier, actually `df.query()` was faster due to my tests. I guess it's because it uses `numexpr` module internally

Comment: Do you need to do the `intersection` thing? It looks to me like you are going through the df index twice, one for creating the intersection and the second to select the slice. Doesn't this work? `df.loc[l.set_index(['numbers','letters']).index]`

Comment: I had a very similar situation in the past, and for me the biggest slowdown turned to be the multi-index, when I switched to a simple index the data access became way faster, so maybe multi-index access is not as optimized?

Comment: @Javier, yeah, `df.loc[l.set_index(['numbers','letters']).index]` works faster, but it's still slower compared to `df.query()` method. I'll update timings

Comment: That is very interesting, there must be some crazy optimization going on in `numexpr`! I would still advise to switch the df to a simple index if possible, in my case it had a dramatic impact (this was some time ago, so pandas might have improved multi-index access by now)

Comment: I meet a new problem. If the list has duplicate rows like: 
    numbers letters
0        0       b
1        1       c
2        0       b
The method doesn't work anymore.

Comment: @JHuang, what about the `.query()` method - it should work also in this case

Comment: I tried. It didn't work either. They got the same answers.

Comment: @JHuang, i'd suggest you then to open a new question and provide there a reproducible (with duplicates) data set

Comment: Fine, I'll open a new question soon.

Answer (score 1):

assuming you have the following DF with the values that you want to get:

```
In [28]: l
Out[28]:
   numbers letters
0        0       b
1        1       c
```

if you need to select all rows where `numbers` is either `0` or `1` and `letters` is in `['b','c']` you can use `df.query()` method as follows:

```
In [29]: df.query("numbers in @l.numbers and letters in @l.letters")
Out[29]:
                      dates         0
numbers letters
0       b        2013-01-01 -1.515866
        b        2013-01-02  0.351942
        b        2013-01-03 -0.245463
        c        2013-01-01 -0.253103
        c        2013-01-02 -0.385411
        c        2013-01-03 -1.740821
1       c        2013-01-01 -0.108325
        c        2013-01-02 -0.212350
        c        2013-01-03  0.021097
        b        2013-01-01 -1.922214
        b        2013-01-02 -1.769003
        b        2013-01-03 -0.594216
        c        2013-01-01 -0.419775
        c        2013-01-02  1.511700
        c        2013-01-03  0.994332
```

or simply:

```
df.query("numbers in [0,1] and letters in ['b','c']")
```

**UPDATE:** if it must be exact matches, like `(0, 'b')` and `(1, 'c')`:

```
In [14]: q = l.apply(lambda r: "(numbers == {} and letters == '{}')".format(r.numbers, r.letters),
    ...:             axis=1) \
    ...:      .str.cat(sep=' or ')
    ...:

In [15]: q
Out[15]: "(numbers == 0 and letters == 'b') or (numbers == 1 and letters == 'c')"

In [16]: df.query(q)
Out[16]:
                      dates         0
numbers letters
0       b        2013-01-01 -1.515866
        b        2013-01-02  0.351942
        b        2013-01-03 -0.245463
1       c        2013-01-01 -0.108325
        c        2013-01-02 -0.212350
        c        2013-01-03  0.021097
        c        2013-01-01 -0.419775
        c        2013-01-02  1.511700
        c        2013-01-03  0.994332
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But if I do like this, I will get extra rows which I don't need. Is there an improvement?

Comment: @JHuang, i've added another solution - please check

Comment: Thank you again. But this method isn't fast enough when the data is very large since I should type all conditions by myself.

Comment: @JHuang, no, you shouldn't type anything - i just forgot to add `In [14]` first, now it's fixed. BTW i have added an alternative solution as an extra answer