# How to select a duplicate subset from a Multi-Index Dataframe based on conditions from another DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates, multi-index

I have a dataframe like below:

```
                     dates         0
numbers letters               
0       a       2013-01-01  0.261092
                2013-01-02 -1.267770
                2013-01-03  0.008230
        b       2013-01-01 -1.515866
                2013-01-02  0.351942
                2013-01-03 -0.245463
        c       2013-01-01 -0.253103
                2013-01-02 -0.385411
                2013-01-03 -1.740821
1       a       2013-01-01 -0.108325
                2013-01-02 -0.212350
                2013-01-03  0.021097
        b       2013-01-01 -1.922214
                2013-01-02 -1.769003
                2013-01-03 -0.594216
        c       2013-01-01 -0.419775
                2013-01-02  1.511700
                2013-01-03  0.994332
2       a       2013-01-01 -0.020299
                2013-01-02 -0.749474
                2013-01-03 -1.478558
        b       2013-01-01 -1.357671
                2013-01-02  0.161185
                2013-01-03 -0.658246
        c       2013-01-01 -0.564796
                2013-01-02 -0.333106
                2013-01-03 -2.814611
```

Now I was given a query list like:

```
   numbers letters
0        0       b
1        1       c
2        0       b
```

I need to select data whose indexs satisfy the list. The answer is like:

```
                     dates         0
numbers letters               
0       b       2013-01-01 -1.515866
                2013-01-02  0.351942
                2013-01-03 -0.245463
1       c       2013-01-01 -0.419775
                2013-01-02  1.511700
                2013-01-03  0.994332
0       b       2013-01-01 -1.515866
                2013-01-02  0.351942
                2013-01-03 -0.245463
```

How can I select the specific data from the Dataframe of MultiIndex to answer the query list with duplicate rows? It's important to note that the query list is much longer than the length of dataframe. As a result, I need a fast enough method to solve this problem.

(PS, there is another question like this problem but without duplicate queries.
[How to select a subset from a Multi-Index Dataframe based on conditions from another DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42733118/how-to-select-a-subset-from-a-multi-index-dataframe-based-on-conditions-from-ano))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you convert the second `DataFrame` to a `MultiIndex`, you can just select the first `DataFrame` using `.loc`

```
In [2]: idx = df2.set_index(['numbers', 'letters']).index

In [3]: print df.loc[idx]
                      dates         0
numbers letters
0       b        2013-01-01 -1.515866
        b        2013-01-02  0.351942
        b        2013-01-03 -0.245463
1       c        2013-01-01 -0.419775
        c        2013-01-02  1.511700
        c        2013-01-03  0.994332
0       b        2013-01-01 -1.515866
        b        2013-01-02  0.351942
        b        2013-01-03 -0.245463
```

Comment: Thanks, it's exactly what I want!